# Nifi process group scheduling using control m

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to Nifi.My requirement is to trigger Nifi process group using external scheduling tool called Control M. I tried using shell script to start and.stop the process group using curl command. Process group will fetch data from text file and writes into a database but unable to determine when the process group gets completed because I could see status like Started, Running and Stopped but not Completed state. Struck with this issue and need your valuable inputs on this of how to determine all the records got inserted into database placed inside process group

Answer (score 0):

NiFi is not a batch 'start & stop' style tool. NiFi is built to work with continuous streams of data, meaning that flows are 'always on'. It is not intended to be used with batch schedulers like ControlM, Oozie, Airflow, etc. As such, there is no 'Completed' status for a flow.

That said, if you want to schedule flows in this way, it is possible - but you need to build it in to the flow yourself. You will need to define what 'Completed' is and build that logic in your flow - e.g. MonitorActivity after your last processor to watch for activity.